# Any element $\sigma$ of symmetric algebra over a 2D vector space $V$, $\sigma\in S^{2k}(V)$, induces a map $S^{k}(V^*)\to S^{k}(V)$...

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ be a two dimensional vector space over an algebraically closed field $K$ (I'm not sure but I think we also need $\mathrm{char}(K)=0$, but don't assume it unless necessary). Let $S(V)$ be the symmetric algebra over $V$. If $n=2k$, 
define $W=\{\sigma= \sum_{m=1}^k v_m^n|v_m\in V\}\subset S^n(V)$.
Then I want to find out the following things:

> Any $\sigma\in S^{n}(V)$ induces a (natural) map $F_\sigma: S^k(V^*)\to S^k(V)$.
>
> - Define $F_\sigma$.
> - Prove that $F_\sigma$ is an isomorphism if and only if $\sigma\notin W$.
> - (**EDIT**: THIS IS WRONG) Show that there exist a non-zero $f\in S^k(V^*)$ such that $\forall \sigma\in W: f\in \ker F_\sigma$.

The map, I think, is simply, $F_\sigma: S^k(V^*)\to S^k(V)$ given by $f\mapsto f(\sigma)$, where we are treating $S(V)$ as a quotient of tensor algebra $T(V)$. In tensor algebra a functional $f\in [T^{k}(V)]^*$ maps a vector in $v\in T^{2k}(V)$ to $f(v)\in T^{k}(V)$. Knowing that we just quotient out all elements $u\otimes v-v\otimes u$. I even found an explicit form for the map above in basis $\{e_1,e_2\}$ for $V$ and $\{f_1, f_2\}$ for $V^*$ such that $f_i(e_j) = \delta_{ij}$. The explicit form is pretty ugly though.

I'm having trouble with the rest of the problem. I tried doing it by brute force and doing a lot of messy calculations but got nowhere. Can anyone shed some light on how to proceed?

---

**Edit**: Maybe I should say what is the original problem from which this arises. It is an algebraic geometry problem.

> Let $C$ be the Veronese curve in $\mathbb{P}^{2k}$, i.e. a Veronese embedding of $\mathbb{P}^1$ into $\mathbb{P}^{2k}$. The task is to prove that the $k-1$th Secant variety $\mathrm{Sec}_{k-1}(C)$ is a hypersurface (given only by one polynomial) of degree $k+1$.

The first question is (partially) the hint for the question. I have an idea of how to finish the job once I know how to prove the first statement.

Comment: Where is this from? Figuring this out without the context is going to be quite a challenge. (Even *with* the context, this is clearly not written with clarity in mind...)

Comment: Also, I don't understand your definition of $F_\sigma$. And judging from the third part of the problem, I am not sure whether $F_\sigma$ is supposed to be linear (else, $\bigcap_{\sigma \in W} \ker F_\sigma$ is nonempty by virtue of containing $0$). Anyway, who invented the bullshit idea of leaving definitions to the reader?

Comment: Oh I made a mistake in third part, I just fixed it. $F_\sigma$ is linear and I think it is given as $f\in S^k(V^*)$ mapsto $f(\sigma)\in S^k(V)$. The context is actually from an algebraic geometry problem (this is the hint; ironically I cleared it up actually, it is even more vague in reality).

Comment: The source is a grad course I'm taking, so I don't know of a book. The original problem is if $C$ is the Veronese curve, given by Veronese embedding of $\mathbb{P}^1$ into $\mathbb{P}^{2k}$, then the $k-1$th Secant variety $\mathrm{Sec}_{k-1}(C)$ is a hypersurface (given by only one polynomial) of degree $k+1$.